# how to handle multiple uploads?

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, multiple-instances

I'm writing a program that can upload files to multiple FTP servers.

There is a table, at the top row there are the sites, and at the far left column there are the files. through this table I define what should be uploaded to where.

the program is already working, but what i want to do now is to upload the files parallely on each site. so when i hit start each column will go through the rows on its own and upload the files to that site if the content of the specific cell says so. sites can be any number between 1 and 50. and all uploads should be in parallel. (one file at the time for each site)

what i am asking is what is the best way to handle such thing? i know i have to set up multiple uploaders, but what is confusing me is how to keep track what each site is doing. the only thing i can come up with is an array of arrays. where each position is for a site, and the array at that position defines what file is beeing uploaded and all the informations it needs for that. would that be a good solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data into array then use for loop

use this code

```
$web = ['www.firstSite.com','www.secondSite.com']
$user = ['firstUser','secondUser']
$pass = ['firstPass','secondPass']

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($web);$i++)
{
$conn_id = ftp_connect($web[$i]);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id,$user[$i],$pass[$i]);

if (ftp_put($conn_id, $server_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY))
 {echo "Success";} 
else {echo "Failed";}
}
```

Comment: first three lines are the data into string variables  |            echo equal print | ftp_connect & ftp_login & ftp_put are libraries in php to do your ftp work , i think there is libraries like those in vb.net | if statement and for loop | sizeof function to give you the length of array , i will try to convert it to VB soon.

Comment: Try this (http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?468649-Upload-File-via-FTP-%28VB-NET-2005%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom class and use a `List(Of SiteFiles)` for a collection of them. You iterate the sites data and create a new `SiteFiles` object for each site and add the files names to the `Files` property that need to be uploaded to that site. Then when your done making this `List(Of SiteFiles)` then you can iterate each file in `SiteFiles.Files` for each `SiteFiles` object and use threading/async methods if needed and upload the files. This gives you a neat and tidy way to organize what your doing.

```
Public Class SiteFiles
  Public Property Site As String
  Public Property Files As New List(Of String)
End Class
```